# raise class exception pass rock paper scissor game

Tags: python, exception, if-statement

I have this hw here which I am currently stuck on. My professor provided the class exception for us, but I was wondering is anyone can tell me how it works and for some reason when I run this program I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lab3.1.py", line 32, in <module>
    rps_game_winner(game_2)
  File "C:\Python34\lab3.1.py", line 5, in rps_game_winner
    raise WrongNumberOfPlayersError('Wrong number of players!')
WrongNumberOfPlayersError: Wrong number of players!
```

so wondering if someone can tell me what i did wrong or what i can do to make this program better. ty to everyone

```
class WrongNumberOfPlayersError(Exception): pass
class NoSuchStrategyError(Exception): pass

def rps_game_winner(game):
    if len(game) != 2:
        raise WrongNumberOfPlayersError('Wrong number of players!')
        return print ("A WrongNumberOfPlayers error has occurred. \n\n")

    # Write the code for the NoSuchStratgyError
    stop_words = ['R', 'P', 'S']
    if stop_words not in game[0]:
        raise NoSuchStrategyError('No such strategy!')

    # Write the code to determine the winner
    # Write the code to return a List with the winner's name and strategy
    if ("R" in game[0]) and ("S" in game[1]):
        return print (game[0], "wins since Rock beat Scissor\n\n")
    elif ("P" in game[0]) and ("R" in game[1]):
        return print (game[0], "wins since Paper beat Rock\n\n")
    elif ("S" in game[0]) and ("P" in game[1]):
        return print (game[0], "wins since Scissor beat Paper\n\n")
    elif ("S" in game[1]) and ("P" in game[0]):
        return print (game[1], "wins since Scissor beat Paper\n\n")
    elif ("P" in game[1]) and ("R" in game[0]):
        return print (game[1], "wins since Paper beat Scissor\n\n")
    elif ("R" in game[1]) and ("S" in game[0]):
        return print (game[1], "wins since Rock beat Scissor\n\n")

game = [["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"]]# ["Dave", "S"] wins
game_2 = [['Joe','R']] # wrong number of players
game_3 = [['Joe','R'],['Walter','Q']] # no such strategy as 'Q'
rps_game_winner(game)# returns the list ["Dave", "S"] wins since Scissors beat Paper
rps_game_winner(game_2)# raises exception wrong number of players
rps_game_winner(game_3)# raises exception no such strategy as 'Q'
```

Comment: Looks like that's the intended result. Remember that you're defining EXCEPTIONS here, then intentionally throwing them. You SHOULD get an error message with a traceback

Comment: You should read [the tutorial on errors](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html). You should also ask your professor if you find things confusing; that's what they're there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're having trouble understanding what an exception (or rather, an `Exception`!) is. You define them for the purpose of understanding why your code may have failed. For example:

```
class WrongNumberOfPlayersError(Exception):
    pass
```

This is an `Exception` (literally, as it inherits from `Exception` so it can do everything an `Exception` can do) that you've defined to know when you've got the wrong number of players! Therefore

```
players = [("Player 1", "S"), ("Player 2", "P"), ("Player 3", "R")]
rps_game_winner(players)
# this should raise an exception, since there are the WRONG NUMBER OF PLAYERS!
```

You handle these with `try/except` blocks (called `try/catch` in some languages) as such:

```
while True:
    players = get_players() # imagine a function that created this list,
                            # now you're looping over making a new one each
                            # time it's wrong
    try:
        rps_game_winner(players)
    except WrongNumberOfPlayersError as e:
        # handle the exception somehow. You only make it into this block if
        # there are the wrong number of players, and it's already looping forever
        # so probably just...
        pass
    else: # if there are no exceptions
        break # get out of the infinite loop!!
```

In your `rps_game_winner` function, you have the following logic:

```
if len(game) != 2:
    raise WrongNumberOfPlayersError("Wrong number of players!")
    return print ("A WrongNumberOfPlayers error has occurred. \n\n")
```

This is why I think your understanding is slightly flawed. Once you `raise` that exception, the function exits. It never reads the `return` line (which is probably for the best since you can't `return` a print function, it's just `None` for reasons that are outside the scope of this discussion. In Python 2 I believe this would cause your code to fail to run completely)

This of a function like a small machine that does Work for you ("Work" in this case being some sort of computation, or running an algorithm, etc). Once the machine finishes working, it `return`s the result of that Work. However if something goes wrong, it should inform you that "Hey this isn't the result of my work, this is Something Bad," so it `raise`s an exception instead. Essentially: you can either `raise` if something goes wrong, or `return` if everything goes right.

Note that there are more things wrong than this (e.g. you can NEVER throw a `NoSuchStrategyError` with your current code) but that the basics of the issue are in a misunderstanding of what exceptions are for.

Below is an overly abstracted bit of code that should accomplish what you want it to. Keep in mind that I've purposely obfuscated some of the code so it's unusable as a copy/paste. In particular, I'm rather proud of my implementation of win/lose/draw :)

```
R = 0b001
P = 0b010
S = 0b100

class WrongNumberOfPlayersError(Exception): pass
class NoSuchStrategyError(Exception): pass

class RPSGame(object):
    def __init__(self, *players):
        try:
            self.p1, self.p2 = players
            # assume constructed as game('p1','p2')
        except Exception:
            try: self.p1, self.p2 = players[0]
            # assume constructed as game(['p1','p2'])
            except Exception:
                raise WrongNumberOfPlayersError("Only two players per game")
                # no more assumptions, raise that exception
    def start(self):
        print("{0.name} plays {0.human_choice} || {1.name} plays {1.human_choice}".format(
            self.p1, self.p2))
        def winner(p1, p2):
            global R, P, S
            wintable = {R: {R^S: 2, R^P: 1},
                        P: {P^R: 2, P^S: 1},
                        S: {S^P: 2, S^R: 1}}
            resulttable = ["Draw","Lose","Win"]
            return resulttable[wintable[p1.choice].get(p1^p2,0)] + " for {}".format(p1)
        return winner(self.p1, self.p2)

class Player(object):
    rhyme_to_reason = {R:"Rock", P:"Paper", S:"Scissors"}
    def __init__(self, name, choice):
        self.name = name
        try: choiceU = choice.upper()
        except AttributeError:
            # choice is R, P, S not "R", "P", "S"
            choiceU = choice
        if choiceU not in ("R","P","S",R,P,S):
            raise NoSuchStrategyError("Must use strategy R, P, or S")
        choicetable = {"R":R,"P":P,"S":S}
        self.choice = choicetable.get(choiceU,choiceU)
        self.human_choice = Player.rhyme_to_reason[self.choice]
    def __xor__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Player):
            raise NotImplementedError("Cannot xor Players with non-Players")
        return self.choice^other.choice
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.name, self.choice))
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import random, itertools
    num_players = input("How many players are there? ")
    players = [Player(input("Player name: "), input("Choice: ") or random.choice([R,P,S])) for _ in range(int(num_players))]
    scoreboard = {player: 0 for player in players}
    for pairing in itertools.combinations(players, 2):
        game = RPSGame(pairing)
        result = game.start()
        if result.startswith("W"):
            scoreboard[pairing[0]] += 1
        elif result.startswith("L"):
            scoreboard[pairing[1]] += 1
        else:
            pass
        print(result)
    for player, wins in scoreboard.items():
        print("{:.<20}{}".format(player,wins))
```